# Retry read/write until all bytes are transferred or error occurs

Tags: c, comparative-review, error-handling, io, posix

Currently I have a wrapper function for the `read`/`write` system calls, the purpose of which is to eliminate partial transfer scenarios, by retrying until either all data is transferred or the system call fails in trying to do so.

Includes:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Code:

```
int force(ssize_t(*const func)(int, void *, size_t), const int file, void *ptr, size_t size) {
    for (ssize_t r;; ptr = (char *)ptr+r) {
        if ((r = func(file, ptr, size)) == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return -1;
        }
        if (size -= r)
            continue;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This function would be used as such:

```
extern struct Conf conf;
int file = open("file", O_RDONLY);
if (force(read, file, &conf, sizeof(struct Conf)))
    handle_error();
```

If `write` is passed, `ptr` may point to `const` data because `write` does not modify the data pointed to. But `const` casts are considered improper. Should I keep this wrapper, or should I write separate and mostly duplicated, but 'proper' wrappers?

```
int force_read(const int file, void *ptr, size_t size) {
    for (ssize_t r;; ptr = (char *)ptr+r) {
        if ((r = read(file, ptr, size)) == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return -1;
        }
        if (size -= r)
            continue;
        return 0;
    }
}
int force_write(const int file, const void *ptr, size_t size) {
    for (ssize_t r;; ptr = (const char *)ptr+r) {
        if ((r = write(file, ptr, size)) == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            return -1;
        }
        if (size -= r)
            continue;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about EAGAIN

Comment: @pm100 That is for non blocking IO but I am only dealing with regular files

Comment: you didnt say that was the case

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Which of the code is nonstandard? I know that the `read` and `write` functions and `EINTR` are POSIX specific, but what syntax or other elements are nonstandard?

Comment: In addition to `read, write, EINTR` you identified as non-standard, `ssize_t, O_RDONLY, handle_error()` are also non-standard C.  Recommend that you add the Posix tag (and since the limit is 5, drop one).  Further, even with a tag change, posted code does not compile.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The POSIX tag has been added. `hanlde_error()` is a user defined function.

Comment: Please try compiling the posted code (which lacks headers) and then reconsider to post compliable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second choice should be used for a separate reason, an asymmetry between `read` and `write`. In the event that `read` is called via the above function, and EOF is reached before the requested bytes are read, `read` will return 0, resulting in a forever loop. `write` does not need to handle a 0 return, unless `size` is 0, which can be handled by checking `size` **before** the first iteration instead after. The `read` wrapper may return a different value such as `1` signaling an end of file. Local variable names should also be lowercase.

```
int Read(const int file, void *ptr, size_t size) {
    for (ssize_t r; size; size -= r, ptr = (char *)ptr+r) {
        if ((r = read(file, ptr, size))) {
            if (r == -1)
                return -1;
            continue;
        }
        return memset(ptr, 0, size), 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int Write(const int file, const void *ptr, size_t size) {
    for (ssize_t r; size; size -= r, ptr = (const char *)ptr+r) {
        if ((r = write(file, ptr, size)) == -1)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think either of the choices presented are a good option without seeing the code that actually needs to use them.

The `read()` and `write()` functions are low level I/O, I rarely use them and when I do it is generally to read a binary file. If I need to use these low level functions for I/O then it requires a lot more control over the input then is demonstrated by these options.

For general input I prefer [`fgets()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) or [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline), however, I will sometimes use one of the [`scanf()` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). For general output I use the `printf()` family of functions.

Comment: What if I am dealing with file descriptors as opposed to `FILE *`

Comment: 'man fdopen' should help.

Comment: My programs almost invariably interact with only binary files as opposed to text files

Comment: When I find myself reaching for these low-level functions, then memory mapping is often a better alternative.